# 7 clues that fit a squid

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

7 clues that fit an octopus, a monkey, the monkey's brother, the monkey's cousin and a Siamese centaur.

1. small adorned
2. place you can drink
3. after about
4. the kind I like to meet
5. be1oved teacher
6. one thousand imposter
7. "the kid" jacket

Hint:

> The first sentence describes the format of the answer, give or take a few sticks.

Hint:

> A monkey has _ while a centaur has _ and a siamese has double

Comment: Is the [tag:knowledge]/[tag:trivia] tag needed here?

Comment: Added knowledge.  Knowledge is always good, but always second to what is.

Comment: May we have a hint?

Comment: @MahathiVempati there's an error in the title that is corrected inside the main body.  It's on purpose, to serve as a clue.